# Android how to insert data into database outside of the database helper class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

I have set up a SQLite database which is working fine in terms of creating the tables that i need. What i have been trying to do now is insert into the database but from another class (Signup.java). I want to grab text input into edittext and insert this into the database,but only when a button is clicked.

See my DatabaseHelper class below:

```
package com.example.testerrquin.euro2016fanguide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Euro2016.db";
public static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users_table";
public static final String TABLE_CAPACITY = "Capacity_table";
public static final int CapacityOne = 1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_USERS +" (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Forename TEXT, Surname TEXT, Email TEXT, Password TEXT, Country TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_CAPACITY +" (CapacityID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Capacity INTEGER)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAPACITY);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Basically i need to run the line starting with "db.execSQL". I probably need to reference 'db' somewhere to link up to Databasehelper class but not sure. At the moment i am getting 'Cannot resolve symbol 'db'.

```
CompleteB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String grabFirstname = UsernameET.getText().toString();
            String grabSurname = SurnameET.getText().toString();
            String grabEmail = EmailET.getText().toString();
            String grabPassword = PasswordET.getText().toString();
            String grabCountry = CountryDrop.getSelectedItem().toString();

            db.execSQL("Insert into Users_table (Forename, Surname, Email, Password, Country) values ((" + grabFirstname +"),(" + grabSurname +"),(" + grabEmail +"), (" + grabPassword +"), (" + grabCountry +"))");

            Intent i=new Intent(Signup.this,Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do this inside Your helper class. add a method with for example addValues(String grabFirstName,String grabSurename....) etc. and use it with content values to add this into table.

Comment: Then You don´t need to create a new Database object all the time. And in Your case, You get this error because You haven´t defined db

Comment: you have you initialize you `db` with `context` first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare any method that you need in your SQL helper class:

```
public void sampleMethod(String[] arguments) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Column1", arguments[0]);
    values.put("Column2", arguments[1]);
    values.put("Column3", arguments[2]);
    ....
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String grabFirstname = UsernameET.getText().toString();
        String grabSurname = SurnameET.getText().toString();
        String grabEmail = EmailET.getText().toString();
        String grabPassword = PasswordET.getText().toString();
        String grabCountry = CountryDrop.getSelectedItem().toString();

        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context); //replace context with your activity context. "this" would refer to your onClickListener so be careful.

        helper.sampleMethod(new String[]{
           "user",
           "pass",
           "foo",
           "bar",
           ...
        });

      //rest of your code
    }
```

Also, on another note, make sure you close your database when you are done with it. I personally would call getWritableDatabase in each method and then close the database at the end of the method. Something like:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context c;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    c = context;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_USERS +" (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Forename TEXT, Surname TEXT, Email TEXT, Password TEXT, Country TEXT)");
db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_CAPACITY +" (CapacityID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Capacity INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAPACITY);
onCreate(db);
}

public void sampleMethod(String[] arguments) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Column1", arguments[0]);
    values.put("Column2", arguments[1]);
    values.put("Column3", arguments[2]);
    ....
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Where it says "Column1" should i replace these with the columns in the table i want to insert into?

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare "SQLiteDatabase db" instance out side the constructor in your DatabaseHelper.
2. Create a method in DatabaseHelper class which takes param which requires and inserts into db
3. Then in your activity create an instance of DatabaseHelper and call the method which you created in step 2

please check for other singleton patterns

Answer (score 1):

Why not make DatabaseHelper a singleton object by declaring all the methods static?  Then you can call it from anywhere in your activities.